# Cryptsetup with optimized AES version

Tags: encryption, cryptsetup, dmcrypt

I am trying to set up an encrypted partition with dm-crypt and LUKS. I want to use the version of the AES cipher optimized with assembly instructions. I recompiled my kernel and added the required configuration options, but now both ciphers show up with the same name in /proc/crypto, and I am confused which one should I use with cryptsetup to have it working. Both aes-generic and aes-asm show up in /proc/crypto under the same name aes:

```
name             : aes
driver           : aes-asm
module           : kernel
priority         : 200
refcnt           : 2
selftest         : passed
type             : cipher
blocksize        : 16
min keysize      : 16
max keysize      : 32

name             : aes
driver           : aes-generic
module           : kernel
priority         : 100
refcnt           : 1
selftest         : passed
type             : cipher
blocksize        : 16
min keysize      : 16
max keysize      : 32
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://breakpoint.cc/Thesis/html/diplomarbeitch4.html), it's automatic.

> Usually generic implementations of an algorithm have a priority of 100, assembly optimized 200 and hardware support 300. The API takes the algorithm with the highest priority if there is more than one available.

It'll just use `aes-asm` because it has a higher priority.